# Swashbuckle general response codes

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, swagger, swashbuckle

Is there some way to define 'general' response codes that are applicable for all calls.

Eg all calls can return one of the following:

```
400 - Bad request
500 - Internal server error (unknown exception occurred)
503 - Service unavailable (maintenance mode)
```

Instead of copy-pasting the comments and attributes on every end-point it would be nice if I can define it in some central place.

Comment: Have you looked into IDocumentFilters?  _ https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#document-filters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @HelderSepu indeed IDocumentFilter is the solution

```c
// Swagger config
swagger.DocumentFilter<DefaultFilter>();

internal class DefaultFilter : IDocumentFilter
{
    public void Apply(SwaggerDocument swaggerDoc, DocumentFilterContext context)
    {
        foreach (var item in swaggerDoc.Paths.Values)
        {
            UpdateItem(item, "400", "Bad or malformed request.");
            UpdateItem(item, "500", "Internal server error.");
            UpdateItem(item, "503", "Service in maintenance mode.");
        }
    }

    private static void UpdateItem(PathItem item, string key, string description)
    {
        TrySetValue(item.Get, key, description);
        TrySetValue(item.Put, key, description);
    }

    private static void TrySetValue(Operation op, string key, string description)
    {
        if ( (op == null) || (op.Responses.ContainsKey(key)) )
        {
            return;
        }

        op.Responses.Add(key, new Response
        {
            Description = description,
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Bamm I like it! happy to see that you can roll with a small push on the right direction! a lot of people here want to get a full copy/paste solution,  _ Now for the sample answer keep it short no need to put all  the operations a couple should be enough, same with the TrySetValue you don't need the IF, let the copy_pasters figure that by themselves

Answer (score 2):

For anybody using Swashbuckle 5

```cs
//in AddSwaggerGen
c.OperationFilter<GeneralExceptionOperationFilter>();
```

```cs
internal class GeneralExceptionOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        operation.Responses.Add("401", new OpenApiResponse() { Description = "Unauthorized" });
        operation.Responses.Add("403", new OpenApiResponse() { Description = "Forbidden" });

        //Example where we filter on specific HttpMethod and define the return model
        var method = context.MethodInfo.GetCustomAttributes(true)
            .OfType<HttpMethodAttribute>()
            .Single();

        if (method is HttpDeleteAttribute || method is HttpPostAttribute || method is HttpPatchAttribute || method is HttpPutAttribute)
        {
            operation.Responses.Add("409", new OpenApiResponse()
            {
                Description = "Conflict",
                Content = new Dictionary<string, OpenApiMediaType>()
                {
                    ["application/json"] = new OpenApiMediaType
                    {
                        Schema = context.SchemaGenerator.GenerateSchema(typeof(string), context.SchemaRepository)
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```