# Swagger UI Shows all possible responses

Tags: c#, asp.net, swagger-ui, openapi, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

How can I set  swagger to shown all possible responses?

Now only shows the HTTP 200, but there are more possible responses
I have a global exception handling class and I would like to a global solution.

[image: Response]

Nothing, but now i will try some possible solutions.

If i use it:

```
[ProducesResponseType(200)]
[ProducesResponseType(401)]
[ProducesResponseType(404)]
```

at controller method it is work and swagger shows more possible responses. But i would like to a global solution

Is there a swagger settings or something else?

Comment: What library/framework do you use -Swashbuckle, Swashbuckle.AspNetCore, Swagger-Net, NSwag, something else?

Comment: Hi @Helen
My company's project use Swashbuckle.AspNetCore (6.5.0)

Sorry, i am a full beginner intern developer and i cant post the code, because
it is forbidden

Comment: Do these Q&As answer your question -- [Swashbuckle general response codes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51312178/113116), [Is a way to declare common response types to different actions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66747192/113116)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So https://stackoverflow.com/users/113116/helen find the correct and beauty solution.

[Swashbuckle general response codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51312178/swashbuckle-general-response-codes)

[Is a way to declare common response types to different actions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66747192/is-a-way-to-declare-common-response-types-to-different-actions)

What i used for general response handling:
/in AddSwaggerGen

```
options.OperationFilter<GeneralExceptionOperationFilter>();
```

.

```
internal class GeneralExceptionOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        operation.Responses.Add("401", new OpenApiResponse() { Description = "Unauthorized" });
        operation.Responses.Add("403", new OpenApiResponse() { Description = "Forbidden" });

        //Example where we filter on specific HttpMethod and define the return model
        var method = context.MethodInfo.GetCustomAttributes(true)
            .OfType<HttpMethodAttribute>()
            .Single();

        if (method is HttpDeleteAttribute || method is HttpPostAttribute || method is HttpPatchAttribute || method is HttpPutAttribute)
        {
            operation.Responses.Add("409", new OpenApiResponse()
            {
                Description = "Conflict",
                Content = new Dictionary<string, OpenApiMediaType>()
                {
                    ["application/json"] = new OpenApiMediaType
                    {
                        Schema = context.SchemaGenerator.GenerateSchema(typeof(string), context.SchemaRepository)
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you add the following attributes to the methods you can specify the output model and the error

```
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK, Type = typeof(YOUROBJECT))]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
```

Comment: 200 should be unnecessary and specifying object as return type might break showing the real type in swagger.

Comment: It's just demo code, change the object to your object

Comment: I tried it, but it is not working for me..
I used it my exception handler method.

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: Sorry, i am a full beginner intern developer and i cant post the code, because
it is forbidden

Answer (score 0):

Just an additional info, specifically for `java` and `springboot` based apps, we need use combination of `@RestControllerAdvice` and `@ResponseStatus` annotations.

Step 1: Add `@RestControllerAdvice` on `GlobalExceptionHandler`

Step 2: Add `@ResponseStatus(HTTPStatus.INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR)` on
each method that you have handled and want to show.